# Django template detailed view of object

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am wondering how to do so that after creating a new object, a page with the details of the given object is automatically created. Of course, the page according to the template.
I have a list of objects owned by the user and a "details" button next to each object. I would like this button to take you to the details page of this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DetailView` for that case.

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from your_app.models import YourObject

class YourObjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = YourObject
    ...
```

ulrs.py:

```
ulrpatterns = [
    ...
    path('your_app/<int:pk>/', YourObjectDetailView.as_view(), name='your-object-detail'),
    ...
    ]         # pk is the id of the object if you didn't change primary key
```

To get url specified to the object in template:

```
{% url 'your-object-detail' some_id %}
```